# Android Eclipse Error "Android Packaging Problem"

Tags: android

I am getting an error in my Problems tab for my Android Project in Eclipse.  The error is "**Android Packaging Problem**" with an Unknown location.

**Unknown Error NullPointerException**

I cannot determine what this problem is.  My project was working a few hours ago.  The only change I made was to add a ***public interface ITrackDao***  to my project and implement it.  There are no errors associated with this.

I am not even sure where to begin to look.  I cannot launch the application.  Can someone give me an idea on what area I can look into?
Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 39):

I was confronted with this problem too, and I solve it by clicking Menu->Project->Clean. The error goes away after cleaning the project.

Comment: great solution.  saved me hours of headaches.

Comment: I reopened a project in eclipse and was getting this error. This fix helped resolve.

Comment: FYI, in my case it did not work, I had the problem on a library project. I finally succeeded to remove the error by exiting Eclipse first then cleaning the project.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error - but instead of a `NullPointerException` it was an `InvalidoperationException` from somewhere in Eclipse.

A *Project > Clean* solved that one too.

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning the project was not enough for me. I had to first remove a `<classpathentry/>` that specified the interface from the .classpath file and a `<linkedResources>'s <link>` to the same interface in the .project file before cleaning the project would remove the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried the clean up option but for some reason it still did not work. I copied my project and pasted it as a new project and that cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error in an imported project and cleaning was not helpful, however by deleting the library references in the .project and .classpath eclipse files, and then relinking things and cleaning, I was able to get things building again.

Answer (score 0):

First I should recommend that you start using subversion or other versioning on your apps, that way you can pinpoint every change between each iteration. If your project was in subversion you could compare with previous and then pinpoint what changed.

With that said, I would also check through any recently changed layout XML, make a change and hit save and make sure you don't get errors. I've experienced strange null pointer/errors in Eclipse at times when my layout was fine, and by making a change and saving, the errors go away.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem coz of my blackberry sdk installation. I think it messed up my eclipse 3.6.2 install . I just reinstalled eclipse and it all worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I worked with a SVN project and one installation have eclipse Galileo. The other have updated to Helios.
In Helios I found this problem and clean is no solution.
After Galileo reinstall (all installations equals now), I deleted workspace and a new checkout resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried the clean up option but for some reason it still did not work. I solved this problem using this step
Project name ->Android tool ->Add support Library