# Android packaging error - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting an error in my Problems tab for any Android Project i create in Eclipse. The error is "Android Packaging Problem" with an Unknown location.

Error generating final archive: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13    ApiDemos Unknown    Android Packaging Problem

I cannot determine what this problem is and cleaning the project is not solving the problem. I even ran a new project but the same error appears when launching the application.
I am not even sure where to begin to look. Iam using eclipse indigo 64bit with ADT ver 16.0 . Can someone give me an idea on what area I can look into? Thanks

Comment: please give full detailed log print. as you had the same problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865577/android-eclipse-error-android-packaging-problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean your Project for this. On Eclipse main menu goto Project -> Clean.