# Android App Error unknownpackageerror

Tags: android

I am creating simple android application in android of hello world printing and getting an -- error Description

```
Resource    Path    Location    Type Error generating final archive: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13   Demo_ABC        Unknown Android Packaging Problem
```

Code is:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


}
```

Comment: Try to post full stack trace

Comment: Post all lines appearing for you

Comment: i have pasted all the lines of code above and pasted the error to above i am not using any sort of array still getting the error array index out of bounds..etc

Comment: @Mit What is the status of this question?

Comment: @Mit: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835258/android-packaging-error-arrayindexoutofboundsexception?

Answer (score 2):

Someone else had [the same problem with eclipse](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/BvO5g6RMamo). The solution was to check the box "Create Test Project":

> Your project is getting associated with some Test Project which you are not mapping with your newly created project. When you are creating any new project check carefully whether you are including the "Create Test Project" option or not.

Another guess: As the error seems to be package-related and your code does not include that, insert the correct `package yourpackage.tld;` in the code. (you said "Code is:").

Maybe that is missing Android expects it by default and gives weird errors because that was totally unforseen by the Google Android developers.