# How to bring back R.java file on eclipse?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, adt, r.java-file

I am starting to honestly think Eclipse does not want me to finish my project...

Firstly it stops updating my xml files for some reason. Soooo, I decide to clean my project, which makes my R.java file simply disappear. Why in the world did this happen and how can I get it back?

Also, why is aren't my .xml layout files not updating?

Here is the code of the xml file I was working on. It has no indication of an error and I don't see where this error courld be.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.jfitnessfunctiontester.RegisterUserActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ageRegisterTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:text="Age:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/weightRegisterTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ageRegisterTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ageRegisterTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:text="Weight (kg):" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/heightRegisterTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/weightRegisterTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/weightRegisterTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:text="Height (cm):" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ageRegisterEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ageRegisterTextView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ageRegisterTextView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ageRegisterTextView"
    android:ems="3"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="3" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/weightRegisterEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/heightRegisterTextView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/heightRegisterTextView"
    android:ems="3"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:maxLength="3" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/heightRegisterEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/heightRegisterTextView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/heightRegisterTextView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/weightRegisterEditText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:ems="3"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/finishRegisterButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/weightRegisterEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sexRegisterSpinner"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:text="Finish" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sexRegisterSpinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/heightRegisterEditText"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />
```

Thanks

Update: I copied and pasted my old R.java code since I couldn't figure out how to get the new one (Is that ok to do?) And now my program won't even compile saying there are mistakes. The thing is, there are no indications of errors at all!

Update 2: Here are the errors I ended find through the Eclipse problem view:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

C:\Users\Julia\git\FuzzFit\FuzzFit\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist FuzzFit     Unknown Android Packaging Problem
Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.   FuzzFit     Unknown Android Packaging Problem

Update 3: I have up trying to do all this stuff when nothing is working, so reverted to the version I committed yesterday. Surprise surprise I have a whole new set of errors! Apparently one of my Activities is not finding it's layout files. The error messages are that it doesn't exist. But it does!! I am starting to lose my mind here! What I mistake it was to open this project today... What a mistake...

Comment: Check if `Build Automatically` is checked in eclipse...

Comment: Most likely there is some error in one of your resource files, which prevents R from updating.

Comment: @NiekHaarman He already said that eclipse is not updating his xml files..

Comment: Also check out that your file names don't include offending characters, like UpperCase letters, minus (-), and other special chars (only lower case chars, underscore, dot and numbers - not initial) are allowed

Comment: @Lal which is not very clear. Eclipse shouldn't modify xml files at all, so what should it be updating?

Comment: The Build Automatically is checked in eclipse, there are no offending characters in the files and there is no indication of an error. I'll make an edit and post the code of the file I was working on.

Comment: As for the duplicate, I looked through that topic and nothing really helped, as well as the issue seems a bit different.

Comment: It does sound like you have a build problem. Have you looked at the 'Problems' view in Eclipse?

Comment: Please check **all** of your xml files for tiny errors (also strings.xml, for instance). It could be simply a missing **>** or an excess **-** in a comment... look at every single line in every single xml file.

Comment: @AndrewFielden found two in that view: 
Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Julia\git\FuzzFit\FuzzFit\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist FuzzFit  Unknown Android Packaging Problem
Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output. FuzzFit  Unknown Android Packaging Problem

Sorry but I have no idea what they mean.

Comment: Remove `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` from your RelativeLayout ..

Comment: `Unparsed aapt error(s)` is simply removed by deleting the error in the error window. It happens randomly. `resources.ap_ does not exist` should sugegst that something went wrong in compiling some resource file(s) - Check layouts, drawables, menus, preferences, strings, dimens, styles, themes, ...

Comment: You can keep a backup of your project, clean your workspace and then import your project again
Or create a new project and clone it

Comment: Alright. Removed one of the errors as well as those lines fro the RelativeLayout. Still doesn't work and I still have the second error.

Comment: As it stands, I am starting to think this is what I'll have to do. Thank heavens for repositories!

Comment: What is the second error???Please post the Logcat

Comment: and, at last, try restarting Eclipse.

Comment: @Lal my LogCat doesn't say anything. My second error is just: Description Resource Path Location Type
Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Julia\git\FuzzFit\FuzzFit\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist FuzzFit  Unknown Android Packaging Problem

Comment: @DerGolem already did so a couple times...

Comment: Only solution for that problem is Cleaning as said in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865577/android-eclipse-error-android-packaging-problem)

Comment: Do you try to clean and build your project? In most cases this solves the problem.

Comment: Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714711/android-packaging-problem-resources-ap-does-not-exist) too..It has a different answer..

Comment: Make sure "build automatically" is turned on.  If there is a problem in your XML, you should see a red icon on the file.  You can also open the "problems" window and see what it says there.  If there are no problems and build automatically is on, it *should* generate your R file.

Comment: Oh, another thing... sometimes, somehow, something imports the default Android R file.  You probably don't want that.  Check your import statements and make sure only your own R file is being imported.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I already did all that stuff. NOTHING is working. I decided to revert to the old version I committed last night and now I have a while new set of errors. I think I'm going to cry...

Comment: Why dont you try cleaning the project???

Comment: @Lal it was the first thing I did!! What happened when I did so? My R.java file disappeared!

Comment: Try the 2nd answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437023/resources-ap-does-not-exist-when-compile-my-android-project)

Comment: i don't understand what's the problem in creating a new project with similar package name and activities and pasting all the resources, code in it

Comment: @Nikkajihaikjawak unfortunately yours was the only one that worked. After about 2 hours of trying to fix these things I've just reverted to the old version and still have no idea what happened in the first place. Waste time of time unfortunately... Might as well not had done anything =/

Comment: Nope. I had it on Git, so I recovered last nights version of it which had very few differences to it. But I just feel like the passed two hours were a waste because nothing worked and I really have no idea what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright folks! Figured it out!

Turns out it has everything to do with Eclipse's updates, in which in generates the activity a different way than it used to. Instead of generating it with just the layout it also has the fragment layout thing which I still have no idea what it does. Using another users question, I did what other user's told me and got rid of the fragment file and made minor changes on the activity class file.

This worked like a charm yesterday, or so I thought... Until today I decided to change some things and they wouldn't change anymore. The error was in the menu files which are also generated, I just had to delete a couple of lines which made no more sense now. That was it!

Uhh... Now just to get something off my chest: I HATE HATE HATE HATE this update so far it has given me nothing but problems!

Thanks for all your help everyone!